# Не удается прочитать свойство (React)

Tags: reactjs

Консоль выдает ошибку Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Мой код:

```
import React from 'react';
import Categories from '../Categories/Categories';
import GuitarBlock from '../GuitarBlock/GuitarBlock';
import Sort from '../Sort/Sort';

function Home({ guitarItems }) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='content__top'>
                <Categories
                    items={['Gibson', 'Jackson', 'Dean', 'Fender', 'Ibanez']}
                />
                <Sort
                    items={[
                        { name: 'популярности', type: 'popular' },
                        { name: 'цене', type: 'price' },
                        { name: 'алфавиту', type: 'alphabet' },
                    ]}
                />
            </div>
            <h2 className='content__title'>Все инструменты</h2>
            <div className='content__items'>
                {guitarItems.map(obj => (
                    <GuitarBlock key={obj.id} {...obj} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Жалуется на строку 7 (activeLabel). На то, что не видит свойство name у items.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    function Sort({ items }) {
        const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
        const [visiblePopUp, setVisiblePopUp] = useState(false);
        const sortRef = useRef();
        const activeLabel = items[activeItem].name;

    const toggleVisiblePopUp = () => {
        setVisiblePopUp(!visiblePopUp);
    };

    const handleOutSideClick = e => {
        if (!e.path.includes(sortRef.current)) {
            setVisiblePopUp(false);
        }
    };

    const onSelectItem = index => {
        setActiveItem(index);
        setVisiblePopUp(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', handleOutSideClick);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div ref={sortRef} className='sort'>
            <div onClick={toggleVisiblePopUp} className='sort__label'>
                <svg
                    className={visiblePopUp ? 'rotated' : ''}
                    width='10'
                    height='6'
                    viewBox='0 0 10 6'
                    fill='none'
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                >
                    <path
                        d='M10 5C10 5.16927 9.93815 5.31576 9.81445 5.43945C9.69075 5.56315 9.54427 5.625 9.375 5.625H0.625C0.455729 5.625 0.309245 5.56315 0.185547 5.43945C0.061849 5.31576 0 5.16927 0 5C0 4.83073 0.061849 4.68424 0.185547 4.56055L4.56055 0.185547C4.68424 0.061849 4.83073 0 5 0C5.16927 0 5.31576 0.061849 5.43945 0.185547L9.81445 4.56055C9.93815 4.68424 10 4.83073 10 5Z'
                        fill='#2C2C2C'
                    />
                </svg>
                <b>Сортировка по:</b>
                <span>{activeLabel}</span>
            </div>
            {visiblePopUp && (
                <div className='sort__popup'>
                    <ul onClick={toggleVisiblePopUp}>
                        {items &&
                            items.map((obj,index)=> (
                                <li
                                    className={
                                        activeItem === index ? 'active' : ''
                                    }
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        onSelectItem(index);
                                    }}
                                    key={obj.type}
                                >
                                    {obj.name}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

    export default Sort;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в переменной activeItem по умолчанию задается null.
Вы обращаетесь к элементу массива с ключем null – items[null].
 Такого элемента у вас нет, поэтому возвращается undefined.

Возможно вам стоит задать useState(0) для activeItem, тогда будет браться первый элемент.

Comment: да, все верно, уже разобрался, но в любом случае спасибо за ответ!)